# Spiral with perturbation

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to plot a curve similar to the Archimedes spiral that I'm currently plotting as:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[domain=0:25,variable=\t,smooth,samples=500]
    plot ({\t r}: {0.1*\t});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but with a perturbation as in the following picture

[image]

or with a smother perturbation if it's easier to write.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add some noise to the coordinate expression

```
plot ({(\t+0.001*rand) r}: {(0.1+0.002*rand)*\t});
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.pathreplacing}


\tikzset{handmade/.style args={#1 and #2}{%
        rounded corners=.1pt,
        decoration={random steps,segment length=#1,amplitude=#2},
        decorate
    },
        handmade/.default={ 1 and .25},
    }


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

 \draw[handmade={1 and .5}] (0,0)
 \foreach \t [evaluate=\t as \angle using 15*\t,
              evaluate=\t as \r using .02*\t] in {1,...,120}
            {--(\angle:\r) } ;  

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```